# web-scraping in python using beautiful soup: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I am working on a webscraper using html requests and beautiful soup (I am new to this). For 1 webpage (https://www.superdrug.com/Make-Up/Face/Primer/Face-Primer/Max-Factor-False-Lash-Effect-Max-Primer/p/788724) I am trying to scrape the price of the product. The HTML is:

```
<span class="pricing__now" itemprop="price">8.99</span>
```

I have tried using soup.find and soup.find_all:

```
r = session.get(link)
r.html.render(sleep=3, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
price = soup.find('span', itemprop="price").text
```

```
r = session.get(link)
r.html.render(sleep=3, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
price = soup.find_all('span', itemprop="price").text
```

and r.html.find:

```
r = session.get(link)
r.html.render(sleep=6, timeout=30)
price = r.html.find('body > div.pdp-container > div.content-wrapper.pdp > div > div > div.pdp__purchase-options > div.pricing > span:nth-child(2)', first=True).text
```

`None`  and empty lists are returned, or an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`. I am unsure of why I cannot get this information out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the price from Json data embedded within the page. For example:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.superdrug.com/Make-Up/Face/Primer/Face-Primer/Max-Factor-False-Lash-Effect-Max-Primer/p/788724"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

data = json.loads(soup.select('[type="application/ld+json"]')[1].contents[0])

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data["offers"]["price"])
```

Prints:

```
8.99
```